# Marginal means (or "adjusted predictions") with categorical predictors

Tags: r, regression, estimation, marginal-effect

**Goal**

My analysis goal is to estimate the expected value of the outcome variable under three different conditions defined by a set of 3 categorical explanatory variables with two levels each. However, my model also has many categorical variables which i'm treating as covariates (or "nuisance variables").

**Background**

The standard approach of calculating marginal means is computationally expensive in this case, as it requires one to Construct a “grid” of predictor values with all combinations of categorical variables (https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/marginalmeans.html). There are a lot of possible combinations of categorical covariates - possibly more than the sample size.

Another approach to calculating marginal means (Average Adjusted Predictions (AAP); https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/predictions.html) is, in my case, very computationally expensive, as I have a very large sample size, and this takes too long to run in this use case.

**Question**

Thus, I've chosen the approach described as "Adjusted Predictions at User-Specified values" from the link above, where I can estimate the expected value of the outcome under different conditions and keep covariates are set to their means/modes. However because all my covariates are categorical variables, the R packages emmeans and marginaleffects can only set all my covariates to the modal values.

One alternative approach could be to estimate a model where the dummy-coded covariates are set to their means. For example, if i dummy code gender to male (40% of sample) female (40%) and gender_other (10%), I could create a reference grid where gender_female is set to .40 and other is set to .10 (male set to reference category).

Is there anything inherently wrong with this approach? My thought is that there might be given that those packages want to use modes rather than dummy-means.